# Prove that $x^2 + 6x + 9$ is even iff $x$ is odd

Tags: proof-writing, parity

Prove. $x^2 + 6x + 9$ is even iff $x$ is odd.

I had first proved this using a contrapositive statement. However, I was told I was not making a distinction between an if and only if statement, and a conditional statement.

I then wrote the problem again and tried it how I was told. I wrote both out both parts of the iff statement, and I started off with assuming $x$ was odd, or $2k+1$. Then I plugged $2k +1$ into $x^2 + 6x + 9$ to get $4k^2 + 16k + 16$. However, after this I am lost.

Comment: you could write it as $(x+3)^2$ and note that $(x+3)$ and $(x+3)^2$ have the same parity, which is opposite that of $x$

Comment: Factors as $(x+3)^2$ so even/odd only depends on when $x+3$ is odd/even.

Comment: You showed that if $x$ is odd then $x^2+6x+9=4k^2+16k+16$; can you see that's even?  Now show, for the other direction, if $x^2+6x+9$ is even, then $x^2+6x=x(x+6)$ is odd, which means $x$ is odd

Comment: Clearly you can pull a factor of $2$ out of the expression, $4k^2+16k+16$. Since every number divisible by $2$ is even (according to definition), then that would mean...

Answer (score 1):

You showed that, if $x$ is odd, then $x^2+6x+9=4k^2+16k+16$; can you see that's even?

Now show, for the other direction, if $x^2+6x+9$ is even, then $x^2+6x=x(x+6)$ is odd,

which means $x$ is odd.

---

Alternatively, note that $x^2+6x+9=(x+3)^2$ is even$\iff x+3$ is even$\iff x$ is odd.

Comment: Just to add if is not completely clear. $ 4^2+16+16 = 2(2k^2 + 8k + 8) = 2n $ Which means that is even.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I do see that the first part is even. What is the justification for the next part though? Like, why is it x^2 + 6x = x(x+6)? Wouldn't it be x^2 + 6x + 9?

Comment: If $x^2+6x+9$ is an even number, then if you subtract an odd number ($9$), the result ($x^2+6x$) will be an odd number.  That is, if $x^2+6x+9$ is even, then $x^2+6x$ is odd

Answer (score 1):

Simply work in $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$ and use *lil' Fermat*:
$$x^2+6x+9\equiv x+1\bmod 2\equiv \begin{cases}0&\text{if } x\equiv 1\bmod2\\ 1,&\text{if } x\equiv 0\bmod2.\end{cases}
$$